# Passing Int property from textfield back to controller

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, textfield

I am trying to pass data from textfield, back to previous controller using delegation. I am stuck when I try to assign Int value in this call.
This problem is fairly easy, however I cannot find a simple solution. I have been trying different approaches with additional properties that should hold this value, but with no succeed. What do I have to do with this *budgetAmount.text* to be properly converted?

```
protocol BudgetDelegate: class {
func enteredBudgetData(info: String, info2: Int)
 }

class AddBudgetViewController: UIViewController {

var budget: Budget?
weak var delegate: BudgetDelegate? = nil

@IBOutlet weak var budgetName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var budgetAmount: UITextField!

//
@IBAction func saveContent(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if ((budgetName.text?.isEmpty)! && (budgetAmount.text?.isEmpty)!) {
        navigationController?.pop(animated: true)
    } else {
      ->  delegate?.enteredBudgetData(info: budgetName.text!, info2: budgetAmount.text!) 
        navigationController?.pop(animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Error Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int'

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Can you post the delegate's code?

Comment: CSjunkie, added error description. I have to textfields, which one of them is amount field in which I want to type Int value.

Comment: Look at rmaddy's solution below, the issue is you are not converting the string to an Int before passing it to the funciton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `info2` parameter of your protocol method is of type `Int` but you are passing `budgetAmount.text!` which is of course a `String`. You need to pass an `Int`.

Perhaps you need to convert the text in the textfield to an `Int`.

```
delegate?.enteredBudgetData(info: budgetName.text!, info2: Int(budgetAmount.text!) ?? 0)
```

BTW - you are making several terrible uses of the `!` operator. You should spend time learning about optionals and how to safely work with then.

Comment: Yes, thanks for quick response and input. I was missing ?? 0

Comment: Your were also missing the conversion to an `Int`.

Comment: I have tried this conversion but did not type this part above.

Comment: I call the `!` operator the "crash if nil" operator. New Swift developers should pretend it doesn't exist until they get a solid understanding of optionals.

Comment: @DuncanC Sadly it is the fault of Xcode since it helpfully suggests that you add `!` when trying to pass an optional to a non-optional value.

Answer (score 0):

So based on your question, you just want to pass an `Int` data coming from a `UITextField`. And based on your description, you do not have any problem with delegation.

Converting a `String` into an `Int` is easy:

Example:

```
let num = "1"
if let intNum = Int(num) {
    // There you have your Integer.
}
```